# How to convert a given date with a specified date format using dual table on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the example

`2016-02-06T06:06:41+00:00`

will be converted to

```
2/6/2016  6:06:00 AM
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` to get a formatted string from a timestamp:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2016-02-06 06:06:41 +00:00', 
               'fmdd/mm/yyyy  fmhh:mi:ss am') from dual;
```

(The `FM` in the format exist to suppress leading zeros.)

Comment: Hi @Thorsten Kettner Thanks for your response is there a way to make the am - pm be dynamic currently it is just being hardcoded.

Comment: `am` is not a hard-coded string. `am` (or also `pm`, `AM`, `A.M.`) is the Meridian indicator for the time, see [Datetime Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

Comment: `fm` is like a switch for leading zeros, i.e. `to_char(timestamp '2016-02-06 06:06:41 +00:00', 'fmdd/mm/yyyy  fmhh:mi:ss am')` returns `6/2/2016  06:06:41 am`. `fmdd/mm/yyyy hh:fmmi:ss am` gives `2/6/2016 6:06:00 AM`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you your response @Wernfried Domscheit I understand it now that it is already dynamic when I tried to change the time to afternoon.